# How do html, body and window interact while scrolling programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to implement a scroll-to-top button. Searching online I found this piece of code:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

I am confused, why would they try to scroll both `html` and `body` and then playing around with `overflow: hidden` on `body` tag, I noticed you can't have a scrollbar for both `html` and `body`. Then on MDN I found another way to achieve the same thing as:

```
window.scroll({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

As we know `window` is the global object, which obviously can't be scrolled.

1. Does  `window.scroll` internally scroll the `html` element or the `body` element?
2. Can `body` element be scrolled at all? I tried `overflow: hidden` on `html` and then `overflow: scroll` on `body` but don't see a scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.scroll()` effectively scrolls the [`document.scrollingElement`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#ref-for-dom-document-scrollingelement)* which is now defined as being the `<html>` element, but used to be the `<body>` one in some UAs and still in Quirks mode.

This `document.scrollingElement` is a relatively recent addition and that's why you may still find old code that dealt with both `<body>` and `<html>` to honor all browsers.

*<sub>Per specs it scrolls the "*viewport*" but that boils down to the same since the step 12 of the [`scroll` algorithm](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scroll) passes the " document’s root element as the associated element" to the actual "Perform a scroll" operation.</sub>

```js
const frameContent = `<html>
  <body><h1 style='height:300vh'>%s Mode</h1>
  <script>
    scroll(0, 200);
    parent.postMessage({
      compatMode: document.compatMode,
      html: document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      body: document.body.scrollTop,
    }, '*')
  <\/script>`;
document.querySelectorAll("iframe").forEach((el, i) => {
  el.src = `data:text/html,` + encodeURIComponent(
      (i ? "<!DOCTYPE html>" : "") + // set the first frame to Quirk mode
      frameContent.replace("%s", i ? "Default" : "Quirk")
    );
});
onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(data)
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: `document.scrollingElement`... makes more sense now. That's why I was wondering(if `document` is `html` element) why `document.scrollHeight` returns undefined -- we need `document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Does  window.scroll internally scroll the html element or the body element?

Neither. It scrolls the *viewport*. The precise description of the scrolling is given in [the CSSOM view spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scroll).

> 2. Can body element be scrolled at all? I tried overflow: hidden on html and then overflow: visible on body but don't see a scrollbar.

Yes. but `overflow: visible` won't display a scrollbar. You need `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`. And to make it scroll, the content must overflow the body. e.g.

```css
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 630px;
}  
body { 
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Here you can see two vertical scrollbars. The one on the viewport, forced to display by the `overflow: scroll` on the html element, and the one on body because the content overflows it, and it has `overflow: auto`.

We can make both scrollbars scrollable if both are overflowed by their contents.

```css
html  {
  overflow: auto;
  border:2px solid red;
}  
body { 
  height: 110vh; /* overflows the viewport - but note: 
                    as you can see from the red and 
                    blue borders, not the html emlement. */
  overflow: auto;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
p { 
  height: 130vh; /* overflows the body element */
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
```

Comment: "Perform a scroll of the viewport to position, [with] document’s root element as the associated element," The scroll is not performed "on neither", but on either.

Comment: Sorry I meant _overflow: hidden on html and then overflow: **scroll** on body but don't see a scrollbar._

Comment: @Kaiido - I'm not sure what your point is. The viewport is neither the html element nor the body element, and while the spec defines an "associated element" for the scroll, it seems that it is just used for the result of hit testing.

Comment: @Kaiido Well, that's not my reading of the spec. The scroll is performed on the _box_, not on the associated element, and the box is the viewport. I suspect we're going to have to disagree on this.

Comment: I added a snippet in my own answer which shows clearly that either one is actually scrolled.

Comment: _Here you can see two vertical scrollbars... ...and the one on body_.  For some reason the scrollbar on `body` is always **unscrollable**. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @user31782 - In the first snippet, the body did not overflow the viewport, so there was nowhere to scroll to. I've added a second snippet where both scrollbars actually scroll.